# Android: how to calculate dp?

Tags: android, layout, size, dpi

I know there are N threads about this question, but I still don't know how to apply width and height for Widgets (buttons, images) on Android.

I have read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
and many other threads, but I don't understand it.

How am I supposed to calculate dpi for a button?

Am I need to know the dpi of the device? (Wikipedia list):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density

But there are plenty other devices with different dpi's!

I have a design in photoshop (800x480), and a button (290x65). I have saved and imported the image button in the newly created 'drawable' folder in my android project. In XML (layout) I inserted the ImageView with the imported button image.

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/btnNewImage"
   android:layout_width="210dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
   android:src="@drawable/new_image" />
```

The image inserted is completely different, it's much more bigger. How am I supposed to calculate the exact width and height values for Android sizes?

Comment: Check out the scaling factors here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11801140/833647 for hdpi make it 1.5 times the size and place it in the hdpi folder, for xhdpi make it 2 times the size, etc.

Comment: 1dp  = 1 pixel @ 160dpi. There's a formula on the very page you've linked to that explains the dp <-> pixel conversion.

Comment: Might help to read: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know the dpi of a device, use the following snippet:

```
 int dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

If you want to convert from dp to pixels:

```
 int px = (int)(dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
```

If you want to convert from pixels to dp:

```
 int dp = (int)(px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
```

Comment: Wait, why the 0.5f? It should just be the density and round the result.

Comment: It's there to round to the nearest integer, instead of just rounding down. ([The Android website](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels) does this in their code samples as well.)

Comment: Interesting. Learn something new every day. :) I'm guessing that's to ensure it's at least 1 px, maybe.

Comment: [Android's developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) recommends `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`

Answer (score 1):

To get your image to show up as the right size, you need to put it in the correct "drawable" folder.  For example, if you have an icon that is 48x48 pixels, it should go in  drawable-mdpi.  Ideally, you should create graphics for each of the folders so that Android can pick the best one based on the screen size and resolution.

I'm using the following guidelines for my icons (which I gleaned from somewhere now forgotten); you can extrapolate on these to figure out what pixel dimensions you need:

```
Recommended drawable sizes - to match size of launcher icon, about 3/8"
36x36 - low
48x48 - med
72x72 - high
96x96 - extra high
```